# Can "fatal disaster" mean man-made misfortune?

Tags: phrases

Yesterday, I talked with a friend and mentioned that the Lord Jesus had the potential of suffering a fatal disaster in Judea, because many people tried to kill Him, like the high priest, King of Herod. He thought I couldn't use "fatal disaster," because this context refers to specifically man-made murders, whereas "fatal disaster" usually refers to an accident or a natural catastrophe. What do you think?

Comment: It's not exactly idiomatic usage, but it's not demonstrably wrong.  At issue mostly would be the many possible nuances of the word "disaster".

Comment: Also, a disaster tends to be something happening to a number of people, not just one (unless someone speaks of their personal disaster).  So for instance the Japanese tsunami was a natural disaster, 9/11 was a manmade one.

Comment: A *disaster* need not be *fatal*, but something *fatal* could be a *disaster*, especially for the person concerned, but - as @jamesqf has said - 'disaster' more usually refers to something affecting a substantial number of people.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective *fatal* refers to (according to Merriam-Webster):

> 1   (obsolete) fated
>
> 2   fateful
>
> 3
>
> > a:  of or relating to fate
> > b:  resembling fate in proceeding according to a fixed sequence
> > c:  determining one's fate
>
> 4
>
> > a:  causing death
> > b:  bringing ruin
> > c :  causing failure

Although some of the definitions have an aura of "nature" (or fate, whatever), it is perfectly acceptable to say something like

> He connected the wrong wire to the electric board, an act that had fatal consequences.

Comment: I suspect the question centers more around "disaster".

Answer (score 0):

Most dictionaries define "disaster" as being accidental in nature, so i don't think attempted murder qualifies.  The phrase "fatal disaster" sounds very odd but i can't explain why exactly.

Having said that, the trip as a whole might commonly be described as a disaster, or "disastrous".  Eg

*Mary: "How was your trip to Judea?"*

*Jesus: "It was a disaster!  An angry mob tried to kill me."*

This would be a commonly accepted usage.